# How to create a modal popup using javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dhtml

Actually, two questions:

- How can I create a modal popup with background color of gray?
- Also I need to create for a cover background color only to table itself. Not to overall page.

How do I do this using javascript and css?

Comment: Had to unwind that question a little.

Comment: Duplicate of the question you asked on April 7th: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724103/how-to-create-a-modal-popup-using-javascript

Comment: Guess it wasn't that urgent after all..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the HTML, which should probably be inserted with JS, and the styles should be in an external stylesheet.

```
<div style="background: gray; width: 200px; height: 200px; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -100px; margin-top: -100px" id="modal">I'm a modal</div>
```

Then, you could leverage jQuery to display it.

```
$('a.modal').bind('click', function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#modal').fadeIn(800);
});
```

This is only a start, you'll want to learn from this and build upon it. For example, the script should check `is(':hidden')` and show, and if not then `fadeOut(800)` or similiar.

Answer (score 6):

I use this for the mask that sits on top of the screen

```
.Mask {
   display: none;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 9000;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   background: transparent url(http://i.imgur.com/0KbiL.png);
   position: fixed;
   top: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: What does the mask.png file look like?

Comment: 1x1px png which has .6 opacity.

Comment: @Ballsacian1 can you post a link to this png?

Comment: How are clicks outside the modal prevented from interacting with the elements outside it?