# Display Dialog Box In Order to Add New Row to HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog, html-table

So I currently have an HTML table where I can add rows to the end of the table. A new row appears with text boxes inside and you can enter information.

However, I am wanting to do away with that and use a new method. I am wanting it so that when the `add row` button is clicked, a `dialog box` pops up and gives me the option to add the information for the row. Then it uses the `validation` to make sure the row is good to go and then adds the row to the table.

How would I be able to do this?

You can see the demo...

http://codepen.io/Rataiczak24/pen/wzpJop

JavaScript:

```
// ----- Deactivate/Activate Row -----

$(document).on("click", "#html_master .deactivate", function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $tr = $this.closest('tr');
  var action = $tr.hasClass('deactivated') ? 'activate' : 'deactivate';

  // ------ Confirmation box in order to deactivate/activate row -----
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to ' + action + ' this entry?')) {
    $tr.toggleClass('deactivated');
    $this.val(function (i, t) {
      return t == 'Deactivate' ? 'Activate' : 'Deactivate';
    });
  }
});

// ----- Edit Row -----

$(document).on("click", "#html_master .edit", function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').not('.mr_id').filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
  });
  if ($this.val() === 'Edit') {
    $this.val('Save');
    tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
  } else {
    var isValid = true;
    var errors = '';
    $('#myDialogBox').empty();
    // changed from here.......
    var elements = tds;
    if (tds.find('input').length > 0) {
      elements = tds.find('input');
    }
    elements.each(function (index, element) {
      var type = $(this).attr('class');
      var value = (element.tagName == 'INPUT') ? $(this).val() : $(this).text();
      // changed from here....... to here
      // ----- Switch statement that provides validation -----
      switch (type) {
        case "buyer_id":
          if (!$.isNumeric(value)) {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Buyer ID\n";
          }
          break;
        case "poc_n":
          if (value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/)) {
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Name\n";
          }
          break;
        case "poc_e":
          if (value == value.match(/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/)) {
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Email\n";
          }
          break;
        case "poc_p":
          if (value == value.match('^[0-9 ()+/-]{10,}$')) {
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Phone Number\n";
          }
          break;
      }
    })
    if (isValid) {
      $this.val('Edit');
      tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
    } else {
      alert(errors);
    }
  }
});


// ----- Add Row -----

function addRow(tableID) {

  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell1.innerHTML = rowCount;
  cell1.className = 'mr_id';

  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var element2 = document.createElement("input");
  element2.type = "text";
  element2.name = "txtbox[]";
  element2.className = 'mr_name';
  cell2.appendChild(element2);

  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var element3 = document.createElement("input");
  element3.type = "text";
  element3.name = "txtbox[]";
  element3.className = 'buyer_id';
  cell3.appendChild(element3);

  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var element4 = document.createElement("input");
  element4.type = "text";
  element4.name = "txtbox[]";
  element4.className = 'poc_n';
  cell4.appendChild(element4);

  var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
  var element5 = document.createElement("input");
  element5.type = "text";
  element5.name = "txtbox[]";
  element5.className = 'poc_e';
  cell5.appendChild(element5);

  var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
  var element6 = document.createElement("input");
  element6.type = "text";
  element6.name = "txtbox[]";
  element6.className = 'poc_p';
  cell6.appendChild(element6);

  var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
  var element7 = document.createElement("input");
  var element8 = document.createElement("input");
  element7.type = "button";
  element8.type = "button";
  element7.name = "edit";
  element8.name = "deactivate";

  var setClass = document.createAttribute("class");
  setClass.value = "edit";
  element7.setAttributeNode(setClass);

  var setClass1 = document.createAttribute("class");
  setClass1.value = "deactivate";
  element8.setAttributeNode(setClass1);

  element7.attr = "class";
  element8.attr = "class";
  element7.value = "Save";
  element8.value = "Deactivate";
  cell7.appendChild(element7);
  cell7.appendChild(element8);
}
```

HTML/PHP:

```
<table id="html_master">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
    <td>Buyer ID</td>
    <td>POC Name</td>
    <td>POC Email</td>
    <td>POC Phone</td>
    <td>Edit/Delete</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="mr_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td class="poc_e" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit">
        <input type="button" class="deactivate" name="deactivate" value="Deactivate"></td>
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
</tbody>
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('html_master')">
</table>

<input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('html_master')">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modal popup. Take a look at it: [How to create a modal popup using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724103/how-to-create-a-modal-popup-using-javascript)

You would have to a create separate div on that modal, put all the required input fields in that sub div.

All you need to do is trigger that popup on "Add row" button click, get the user input, close the popup,  verify the code and inject it into table.

I've written this code for you, I hope it helps

**HTML**

```
    <table border="1" style="width:100%;">
      <thead>
        <tr style="font-weight:bold;">
          <td>Field 1</td>
          <td>Field 2</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tBody"></tbody>
    </table>
    <button onclick="showModal();">Add Row</button>
    <div class="modal" id="modal">
      <div class="content">
        <input type="text" id="field1" placeholder="Field 1" /><br />
        <input type="text" id="field2" placeholder="Field 2" />
        <br />
        <button onclick="addRow();">Add</button>
        <button onclick="closeModal();">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .modal{
      display:none;
      background:#fff;
      opacity:0.9;
      position:fixed;
      top:0;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
     }
    .content{
      width:300px;
      background:#f2f2f2;
      margin:0 auto;
      padding:2%;
     }
```

**JS**

```
    function showModal(){
        document.getElementById("modal").style.display = "block";  
    }
    function closeModal(){
        document.getElementById("modal").style.display = "none";  
    }
    function addRow(){
      var tBody = document.getElementById("tBody");
      var field1 = document.getElementById("field1");
      var field2 = document.getElementById("field2");

        /* Your validation code here */


      var rowData = '<tr>'
                            + '<td>'+field1.value+'</td>'
                  + '<td>'+field2.value+'</td>'
                  + '</tr>';
      if(tBody.innerHTML!=null){
          tBody.innerHTML = tBody.innerHTML + rowData;
      }else{
            tBody.innerHTML =  rowData;
      }
      alert("row has been added!");
      field1.value='';
      field2.value='';
      closeModal();
    }
```

Comment: That makes sense, however, I am not very good with javascript and don't really know how to do that unfortunately